# Ajax скроллинг и кнопка назад в браузере

Tags: javascript, ajax, прокрутка

Всем привет, имею такой код:

```js
    if (localStorage.getItem("windowscrolltopr") !== null) {
        var windowscrolltop = localStorage.getItem('windowscrolltopr');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: windowscrolltop
        }, 900);
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            console.log(windowscrolltop);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 600) {
                $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/getnews.php",
                    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
                    data: {
                        lang: lng,
                        last_id: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-time'),
                        ids: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-news')
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var content = document.getElementById("news-list");
                        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + response;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }



$("#more-news").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getnews.php",
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        data: {
            lang: lng,
            last_id: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-time'),
            ids: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-news')
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var content = document.getElementById("news-list");
            content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + response;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }

    });
    localStorage.setItem('windowscrolltopr',$(window).scrollTop());
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#more-news').offset().top - 90
    }, 900);
});
```

При нажатии на кнопку еще, у меня выгружается контент, когда пользователь кликает на новость и переходит читать ее, то js не понимает, что если он нажмет на кнопку назад, то он захочет вернутся на ту новость, где скролил. Я попытался сделать это все при помощи localStorage, но у меня не получается именно определить если он нажал кнопку назад и только тогда грузить контент и возвращать его в ту точку, где он был, есть идеи?

Comment: У Вас не получается определить что он нажал на кнопку "назад" или у Вас не получается вернуть на тот уровень скролла что был до клика по новости?

Comment: Именно что он нажал на кнопку назад, так-то он возвращает